# change image of PhysicsBody when it is resting

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-physics, cocos2d-x-3.0

I created a game that allows users to tap the screen and create box sprites. The sprite is just a simple image of a box and then I create a physics body for the sprite.

In my update method I continuously check all of these block sprites to see if they are resting or not. If they aren't resting, I want the box image to be a certain file. If they are resting, I want the box image to be a different image file. For some reason the sprites change to the image I want when the sprites aren't resting, but they never change to the image I want when they are resting.

```
for (int i = 0; i < blockVector.size(); i++)
{
    if (!blockVector.at(i)->getPhysicsBody()->isResting() && blockVector.at(i)->getPhysicsBody()->getTag() == 1)
    {
        blockVector.at(i)->setTexture("PTBlock2.png");
        blockVector.at(i)->getPhysicsBody()->setTag(2);
    }
    else if (blockVector.at(i)->getPhysicsBody()->isResting() && blockVector.at(i)->getPhysicsBody()->getTag() == 2)
    {
        blockVector.at(i)->setTexture("PTBlock.png");
        blockVector.at(i)->getPhysicsBody()->setTag(1);
    }
}
```

Tag value of 1 = PTBlock.png, 2 = PTBlock2.png.
I added the tags so that the blocks wouldn't keep setting their image to the same thing each time the update method is called. They will only change their image if they are changing to a different image.

Anyway I checked and the reason the image never changes back to PTBlock.png is that the blocks keep returning false for isResting(). Why is this? I have gravity enabled so the blocks will be moving at first but then after they hit the ground they stop moving, so shouldn't they be considered resting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to know more about how to use isResting. In CCPhysicsBody.cpp, here's what we find:

```
bool PhysicsBody::isResting() const
{
    return CP_PRIVATE(_info->getBody()->node).root != ((cpBody*)0);
}
```